# Rails declarative_authorization project_admin role

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, declarative-authorization

I am trying to create project admin and project collaborator roles using the [declarative_authorization](https://github.com/stffn/declarative_authorization) gem.

I have a table called 'collaborators' which holds the users to projects mappings.

Models:

Project

```
has_many :collaborators  
has_many :users, :through => :collaborators
```

User

```
has_many :collaborators
has_many :projects, :through => :collaborators
```

Collaborator

```
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :project
```

I need some guidance on defining the dsl for project_admin and project_collaborator role.
I have come up with the following:

```
authorization do
  role :guest do
    has_permission_on :users, :to => [:read]
  end

  role :project_admin do
    has_permission_on :projects, :to => :manage do
      if_attribute :project_admin => true
    end
  end

  role :admin do
    has_permission_on :users, :to => [:delete]
  end
end

privileges do
  privilege :manage do
    includes :create, :read, :update, :delete
  end
end
```

Appreciate any suggestions/help.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer something like that so that every user could become an project admin:

Project

```
has_many :collaborators  
has_many :users, :through => :collaborators 
belongs_to :admin, :table_name => 'users' # Maybe has_many?
```

authorization_rules.rb

```
authorization do
  role :guest do
    has_permission_on :users, :to => [:read]
  end

  role :user do
    has_permission_on :projects, :to => :create
    has_permission_on :projects, :to => :manage do
      if_attribute :admin => is { user }
    end
    has_permission_on :projects, :to => :read do
      if_attribute :collaborators => contains { user }
    end
    has_permission_on :files, :to => :manage do
      if_permitted_to :read, :project
    end
  end
end

privileges do
  privilege :manage do
    includes :create, :read, :update, :delete
  end
  privilege :read, :includes => [:index, :show]
  privilege :create, :includes => :new
  privilege :update, :includes => :edit
  privilege :delete, :includes => :destroy
end
```